# Find multiple matches using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find all occurrences (there could be zero or more) of anchor(`<a>`) HTML tags with specific attributes/text (to be captured as groups).

**Regex**: `<a\s+.*attr1="myattr".*attr2="(.+)".*attr3="(.+)".*>(.+)</a>`

**Input String**:

```
First <a attr1="myattr" attr2="value12" attr3="value13">text1</a> Second <a attr1="myattr" attr2="value12" attr3="value13">text1</
a> Third <a attr1="myattr" attr2="value12" attr3="value13">text1</a>
```

Outcome: It says only one occurrence found. It is returning the first occurrence of "`<a`" as starting index (of match) which is correct, but it says the last occurrence of "`</a>`" as the end index.
Expected outcome: 3 matches and in each match 3 groups (specified by parentheses in the regex).

Comment: Are there any special reasons why you want to use regex instead of proper HTML parser like jsoup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is by default greedy, so `.*` will match as many characters as possible. You should instead use `.*?` for non-greedy mode.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Non-greedy mode helped fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by user4098326 the problem is the greedyness. Since you used plenty of `.+` groups, they will eat up as much characters as possible until the end of the string.

The `<a\s+.*` (more specific the `.*`) eats up all characters until the last appearance of  `attr1="myattr"`. The remainder of the string then fulfills the remainder of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

[Regex is not best tool for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1393766). Things like easily made mistakes (like in case of using greedy `.*` instead of reluctant `.*?`) are only small part of reason why we should avoid mixing regex with XML/HTML.

- what if attributes are surrounded with `'` instead of `"`?
- What if your HTML contains JavaScript code which has `document.write("<a attr1='foo' attr2='bar'>text</a><br/>")`
- what if element is inside comment?

There are many more and better reasons to avoid regex and HTML. So instead of regex you should consider using proper parser like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

This way your code selecting all `a` tags with attributes `attr1` `attr2` `attr3` can look like

```
Elements elements = doc.select("a[attr1][attr2][attr3]");
```

Demo:

```
String html = "First <a attr1=\"myattr\" attr2=\"value12\" attr3=\"value13\">text1</a>"
        + " Second <a attr1=\"myattr\" attr2=\"value12\" attr3=\"value13\">text1</a>"
        + " Third <a attr1=\"myattr\" attr2=\"value12\" attr3=\"value13\">text1</a>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.select("a[attr1][attr2][attr3]");

for (Element el: elements){
    System.out.println(el);
    System.out.println(el.attr("attr1"));
    System.out.println(el.attr("attr2"));
    System.out.println(el.attr("attr3"));
    System.out.println(el.text());
    System.out.println("--------------");
}
```

Output:

```
<a attr1="myattr" attr2="value12" attr3="value13">text1</a>
myattr
value12
value13
text1
--------------
<a attr1="myattr" attr2="value12" attr3="value13">text1</a>
myattr
value12
value13
text1
--------------
<a attr1="myattr" attr2="value12" attr3="value13">text1</a>
myattr
value12
value13
text1
--------------
```